# Rotativa ActionAsPdf giving 'Access is denied' without username & password.(Windows Authentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, rotativa

Below is Code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadPdf(int id, int pid)
{
    string userName, password = string.Empty;
    userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminUsername"];
    password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPassword"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) && id > 0 && pid > 0)
    {


        var pdf = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("PdfPartial", new { id = id, pid = pid })
        {
            UserName=userName,
            Password=password,
            FileName = "AFE.pdf",                    
        };
            return pdf;
    }
    else
    {
        return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("PdfError")
        {
            FileName = "AFE.pdf",
        };
    }
}
```

I am using windows authentication with Active Directory. I don't want to use username and password in web.config.Is it any way to achieve this? It can be possible if there is any way to access specific mvc action anonymously while using windows authentication.

Comment: I  think you will need to allow anonymous on that partial, I bumped into the same problem while using rotativa but then I switched to iTextSharp which has a lot more features and, from my point of view, it's easier to work with :)

Comment: Why not using ViewAsPdf instead of ActionAsPdf? So you would have no need to manage authentication.

Comment: I have tried with ViewAsPdf but there is ajax used in .cshtml(view) to populate drop down and more, this also required authentication.To overcome this I have added <location path="Controller/Action"> in web.config to allow anonymous access.I have much ajax method so web.config going to be messy. Is there any good approach to do same?